# Defining array of cells/strings

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have quite a big array of strings that's in the format `['name1';name2';...]`, where names don't have the same size.

I know I have to use cells in MATLAB, but I can't figure out how to use it in this case.

The best I came up with was this, but it doesn't work.

```
names = cell(1,n);
names(1:n) = ['name1';'name2';...;'namen'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell array concatenation operator is `{}`;

```
names = {'name1';'name2';...;'namen'};
```